# What are the limitations of the BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: .net, wcf

I should develop a client application (for Windows Phone 7) that is able to send requests to a web service created using WCF. The applications that run on Windows Phone 7 can only send HTTP calls, therefore they can use only BasicHttpBinding as regards WCF. For this reason, I have to use `BasicHttpBinding` in the client application.

Which types of web services can communicate with a client that supports only `BasicHttpBinding`? Should these web services also be developed using the same binding?

Has a web service created using `BasicHttpBinding` some limits on the frequency of the *received messages*? Has a client created using BasicHttpBinding some limits on the frequency of the *sent messages*? If so, why? If so, could this limit be changed? If so, is this limit related to received messages from the same client?

Comment: `wsHttpBinding` also uses http.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Do `WSHttpBinding` web services support `BasicHttpBinding` clients?

Comment: No, of course not. You didn't say the limitation was `basicHttpBinding`, you said the limitation was http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that supports SOAP 1.1 should be able to call a service using BasicHttpBinding.

As far as limits go, the only limits for a service is how quickly your application can process the incoming messages.  There is a default limit of 64KB size per message, but you can adjust that by changing the [MaxReceivedMessageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) setting.

You may want to look at this question for more information on BasicHttpBinding vs WsHttpBinding:
[basicHttpBinding vs wsHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106715/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding)

Comment: I read that `WSHttpBinding` supports SOAP 1.2, therefore a WSHttpBinding web service doesn't support BasicHttpBinding clients...

Comment: I believe that if you wanted to support both, you would need to configure two different Endpoints.

Comment: So should I configure a BasicHttpBinding additional endpoint dedicated to BasicHttpBinding clients?

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are.  If you don't need the advanced functionality in WsHttpBinding, you could just support one Endpoint with BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: Otherwise, I should support one endpoint with WsHttpBinding and one endpoint with BasicHttpBinding.