# BasicHttpBinding and WsHttpBinding in a single ASMX web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

How we can use both httpbasic and ws-* binding in a single web service. I know this is possible from WCF, but need to know if it is possible through ASMX (old) web service. If yes, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106715/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: That means, no, ASMX has no support for wsHttpBinding, or anything other than "basic".